# Is there a plugin to get Folder path as parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to allow users to select a folder path as a parameter and get the entire folder path as the parameter value. Is there any plugin for this purpose.

I have explored the File Parameter, this allows to select a **file path** and gives only the file name as output and not the path. 
I also explored the File systems object parameter list, this is used to list the folders inside a file as choices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a String parameter for it? I have several pipelines where I have paths defined as string parameters for use in shell scripts.

Comment: Yes Alex, currently I am using the String Parameter. But for the user, it is difficult since they will not have the option to browse and select. The user needs to copy the path and paste

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure [Filesystem List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin) can't be conigured to meet your needs?

I believe [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter) should allow you to do this. You'd have write as custom groovy, which could be tricky or take time to load.

You could maybe [(request) enhance the Filesystem List Parameter plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52368?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20filesystem-list-parameter-plugin)

Comment: @sree, did you try any of the options suggested; did they work?